# AngularJS | Create chained promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I would like to create a chained promise for my service provider:

```js
this.$get = function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    var $facebook=$q.defer();

    $rootScope.$on("fb.load", function(e, FB) {
        $facebook.resolve(FB);
    });

    $facebook.api = function () {
        var args=arguments;
        args[args.length++] = function(response) {
            $facebook.resolve(response);
        };

        $facebook.promise.then(function(FB) {
            FB.api.apply(FB, args);
        });

        return $facebook.promise;
    };

    return $facebook;
};
```

Than I call to the promise: `$scope.user=$facebook.api("/me");`

The problem is that because the `deferred` was already resolved its not wait until the `api` method will resolve it..

**How can I chain them in a way the last promise will wait until the last promise will resolved?**

Comment: last line of question seems to be confusing could you elaborate more on this step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need two separate promise objects: 
One for the fb.load event and another one for the result of the API call.

Try chaning your code to read -

```
this.$get = function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    var apiLoaded=$q.defer();

    $rootScope.$on("fb.load", function(e, FB) {
        apiLoaded.resolve(FB);
    });
    // You should reject the promise if facebook load fails.

    $facebook.api = function () {
        var resultDefer = $q.defer(),
            args=arguments;

        args[args.length++] = function(response) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                resultDefer.resolve(response);
                // you should reject if the response is an error
            });
        };

        return apiLoaded.promise.then(function(FB) {
            FB.api.apply(FB, args);
            return resultDefer.promise;
        });
    };

    return $facebook;
};
```

Also note that whenever you call resolve() from non-angularish code, you will need to wrap it with $rootScope.$apply(), otherwise then promise 'then' handlers will not get executed. Good luck!

Comment: its seems that right now it not resolve it at all..
I think I need to return something in the `then` part, but the result is inside the Facebook callback!

Comment: It actually seems like you need two promises, please see my edited answer.